# Web Api request invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i have a route:

```
routes.MapRoute (name: "apicontroller2",
                 url: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Default2", action = "Index" }
                );
```

and the Default2Controller with two post methods:

```
[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ttReview review)
{
...
}

[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage PostPro(ttbewertungenpro pro)
{
...
}
```

when i call these API-Methods via `webserver/api/default2/PostPro/` or `webserver/api/default2/Post/` ajax post i get the error:

```
ExceptionMessage=Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post(WT.Models.ttReview) on type WT.Controllers.Default2Controller
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage PostPro(WT.Models.ttbewertungenpro) on type WT.Controllers.Default2Controller
```

My ajax calls are:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../api/default2/Post", // or "../api/default2/PostPro",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "text", 
        data: review, // or pro
        success: function (test) {
        },
        error: function (test) {
            alert("Error");
        }
}
```

is my route wrong or what?
when i delete one method the other works...

Comment: Posts for /Default2/ will look for Default2Controller, but your controller is named DefaultController2.

Comment: What happens when you rename `PostPro` to `Test` to get rid of the common prefix `Post`?

Comment: Are you sure you need the .. in-front of API in the URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bran new blank WebAPI Project - I have not touched the global.asax file.

Home Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string review)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostPro(string pro)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#submit").click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "home/Post", // or "../api/default2/PostPro",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "text",
                data: "test", // or pro
                success: function(test) {
                },
                error: function(test) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

        });

    });


 </script>


<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
```

This works fine for me, so the problem must be your path/routes.

Answer (score 2):

Check out *AttributeRouting* (http://nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi)

It is so much easier to map your routes.

Example

```
[POST("Page/Method")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ttReview review)
{
...
}
```

Comment: this solves the problem, but i still have to define each route manually. This is more a workaround than the solving of the initial problem. So i don't want to mark it as an answer yet.